# Indexing a vector with a matrix of indicies with numpy, similar to MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, indexing

I want to pull out a matrix filled with the values from a vector indexed with a matrix of indices
i.e. `output(i, j) = vector(indices(i, j))`

In Matlab, this can be achieved with `output = vector(indices)`.

In Python/numpy I have the following loop for this purpose but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it:

```
    idx = np.random.randint(0, 100, (25, 10))
    data = np.random.random(100)
    output = np.empty((np.size(idx, 0), np.size(idx, 1)))
    for i in range(0, np.size(idx, 0)):
        output[i, :] = np.squeeze(data[idx[i, :]])
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [547]: idx = np.random.randint(0, 100, (25, 10)) 
     ...: data = np.random.random(100) 
     ...: output = np.empty((np.size(idx, 0), np.size(idx, 1))) 
     ...: for i in range(0, np.size(idx, 0)): 
     ...:    output[i, :] = np.squeeze(data[idx[i, :]]) 

In [553]: idx.shape                                                                                       
Out[553]: (25, 10)
In [554]: output.shape                                                                                    
Out[554]: (25, 10)
```

Simply index; no need to iterate

```
In [555]: np.allclose(output, data[idx])                                                                  
Out[555]: True
```

There are differences between MATLAB and `numpy` when indexing with two arrays, one for each dimension.  To put is simply, in MATLAB it's easier to index a block, in `numpy` indexing a diagonal is more direct.  But that's not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Output=vector[x, y]
```

`X` and `Y` are coordinates that you choose.
Similarly, if you want to specify an interval:

```
Output=vector[X1:X2, Y1:Y2]
```

Just `[]` instead of `()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Bans Akin. Unless I have misunderstood your suggestion, I don't want to index [X, Y] coordinates from a 2D array. Rather I want to index a 1D array iteratively using indices from a 2D array, output into a corresponding 2D array.